# Adding external Jar file to ant build in a Bash Script

Tags: java, bash, ant

I have reviewed numerous posted questions related to this but can't seem to come to a clear solution.  I am attempting to use emma to provide code coverage for an application and robotium as a testing unit.  The external dropbox.jar is in the build path within eclipse.

The application and test cases run successully within Eclipse however when running the script, ant is unable to locate the dropbox.jar dependencies.  Below is my script, followed by a section of the log from the ant call

```
#!/bin/bash
#Code Coverage Script:
#(android:command not found error)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Deverick/android-skds
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/Users/Deverick/Documents/workspace/Diary-Test/libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1:$PATH

echo $PATH
cd ~/Documents/workspace/
cd Diary
ant clean
cd ..
cd Diary-Test
ant clean
cd ..
android  update project --path ./ --name Diary --target android-16 --subprojects
cd Diary-Test
android  update test-project --main ../Diary --path ./
ant emma debug install
ant emma debug install test
```

**Log Output:**

```
 -code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/Deverick/Documents/workspace/Diary/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/Deverick/Documents/workspace/Diary/src/jpf/android/diary/Diary.java:2: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
    [javac] //  Copyright ? 2012  Josep Portella Florit <hola@josep-portella.com>
    [javac]               ^
    [javac] /Users/Deverick/Documents/workspace/Diary/src/jpf/android/diary/Diary.java:39: package com.dropbox.client2 does not exist
    [javac] import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /Users/Deverick/Documents/workspace/Diary/src/jpf/android/diary/Diary.java:40: package com.dropbox.client2.android does not exist
    [javac] import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
```

How might I go about adding this .jar path to the script so it is seen as a dependency? I've seen some references to the $CLASSPATH.  Most questions referring to this used the build.xml file to add the dependency however the script cleans the build.xml each time. Any clarification is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to report back for the the commmunity, I found the solution to my problem and maybe a problem some developers using `ant` to compile `android applications with external .jars`.

**Ensure that your jar files are immediately located within your libs folder**, that is not in some sub folder of libs.  It seems ant **does not** recursively search subfolders of libs for `.jar` files.

Running the script again, the library dependencies are included and errors removed from script.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract from the `ant` manpage. hope this helps.

```
-lib <path>
              specifies a path to search for jars and classes
```